# how to apply accordion effect manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've made some boxes which will be be expanded and hidden by clicking on the titles of the boxes. I've just used slideToggle() for making it. I need another effect. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qheJQ/

On that, I have three boxes: **Slow Task**, **Different type of Task** and **Quick Tasks** When anyone click on the **Slow Task**, the box will be expanded. If user click on **Slow Task** again, that box will be hidden. if user don't click again for hiding the **Slow Task** box and click **Different type of Task**, both the box will remain expanded. So, I want, when user click on **Different type of Task**, this box will be expanded and other boxes will be hidden if they are extended just like [this accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples).

How can I get this **without using any plugin for accordion**?

My Script:

```
$('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.arrow').toggleClass('arrow_up');
    $(this).next('.box_expand').slideToggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some mods to your code that should work -

```
$('.title').click(function() {
    $('.title').not( $(this) ).find('.arrow').removeClass('arrow_up');
    $('.title').not( $(this) ).next('.box_expand').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.box_expand').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.arrow').toggleClass('arrow_up');
 });
```

Tested in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/qheJQ/1/